# Flask: How to return a website outside of the template directory

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to return websites (html files) that are outside of the template directory.

Directory of the .py file:

```
archiv/archiv/web/article/articles.py
```

Directory of the html:

```
instance/articles/private/abc/abc.html
```

My articles.py code:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
bp = Blueprint('articles', __name__, url_prefix='/articles')

@bp.route('/<article>')
def show_article(article):
    """Show a article."""
    base_url = '/instance/articles/private/'
    url_to_return = base_url + str(article) + '/' + str(article) + '.html'
    # return render_template(url_to_return)
    return "Hello " + article
```

The route gets accessed but once i am trying to return the website (comment) i does not work -> template not found. I am pretty sure that render_template isn´t the way to go but i haven´t found anything that could fit.

Could someone show me how to return the website abc.html once the route is called?

Thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a new template directory when creating the blueprint. When you pass a template name to the `render_template` function, it will also check the new location.

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, render_template

bp = Blueprint(
    'articles',
    __name__,
    url_prefix='/articles',
    template_folder="../instance", # New line!
)

@bp.route('/<article>')
def show_article(article):
    """Show a article."""
    return render_template("articles/private/abc.html")

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(bp)
```

From Flask [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Blueprint) (for a Blueprint)

> **template_folder** – A folder with templates that should be added to the app’s template search path. The path is relative to the blueprint’s root path. Blueprint templates are disabled by default. Blueprint templates have a lower precedence than those in the app’s templates folder.

If you want to add that template directory to the whole app, you can set `template_name` when creating Flask instance. Check [this](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask) for more.